# How to remove element from array by key in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have this array:

```
var myArray = [
                  {first_name: "Oded", last_name: "Taizi", id: 1},
                  {first_name: "Ploni", last_name: "Almoni", id: 2}
                  ];
```

An i want to remove the id element? I create function like this but it doesn't work correctly.

```
function removeKeys(array,keys){
 for(var i=0; i<array.length; i++){
    for(var key in array[i]){
        for(var j=0; j<keys.length; j++){
            if(keys[j] == key){
                array[i].splice(j, 1);
            }
        }
    }
 }
}

removeKeys(myArray ,["id"]);
```

The result array should look like:

```
[
    {first_name: "Oded", last_name: "Taizi"},
    {first_name: "Ploni", last_name: "Almoni"}
];
```

Comment: You need to use delete: `delete array[i][key]`

Comment: You're trying to remove a property from an object and not an array.  You can use delete for that

Comment: If you're asking how to remove the `id` property from those objects, this is a duplicate of [*How do I remove a property from a JavaScript object?*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/208105/how-do-i-remove-a-property-from-a-javascript-object)

Comment: Based on your edit, yes, this is a duplicate of the question linked above. I can't dupehammer it (I already voted to close as unclear).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I remove a property from a JavaScript object?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/208105/how-do-i-remove-a-property-from-a-javascript-object)

Comment: sorry i ddin't saw it. the first comment here by @Oskar solve me the problom

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use this:

```
myArray.forEach(function(item){ delete item.id });
```

Comment: If that's what the OP's asking, we don't need *yet another* answer to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/208105/how-do-i-remove-a-property-from-a-javascript-object).

Comment: ...and they've now confirmed that yes, that's what they're asking.

Answer (score 4):

Maybe with a filter on the array:

```js
filteredArray = myArray.filter(item => return (item.id !== id));
```

This will return a new array without the matching element.